# Which term best describes elements of URL path?

Tags: php, http, url, terminology

The term I'm looking for would be able to describe both `users` and `123`:

```
http://example.com:8080/users/123?name=john#hohohohoho
\__/   \______________/\________/ \_______/ \________/
scheme    authority       path      query    fragment
```

Comment: the RFC specs seem to favour: "path component",  "path segment"

Comment: Look **StackExchange** profiles urls...

Comment: @MaciejCzyżewski, Why?

Comment: This also begs the question, for what purpose? In order to communicate about URLs in general, the RFC should be the authority; hence, @Dagon ought to post his comment as an answer.

Comment: @tripleee, I agree that he should.

Comment: ok, if you insist :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a very comprehensive answer however - the RFC specs seem to favour: "path component", "path segment"

from  "[Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)"

**3.3. Path**

...
A path consists of a sequence of **path segments** separated by a slash
("/") character.  A path is always defined for a URI, though the
defined path may be empty (zero length).
...

i would leave *path component* for the whole path

Comment: Could you add a quote?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring RFC, the example of url you provided suggests that `users` in that case is some kind of `param name` and `123` is somewhat `param value`. Also in this particular url, the `users` could mean a `controller name`.

PHP based class routers often offer something like this...

```
/:module/:controller/:action
```

...default route. When user type this url:

```
/blog/category/show
```

...application will assign:

```
module = blog
controller = category
action = show
```

Take a look on: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html

Comment: As the question says, the term I'm looking for would be able to describe both `users` and `123`. The term `controller` would fail in that.